# EC2 Image Builder OVA Import Fail due to Unsupported kernel version 6.1.0

Tags: amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, debian, ec2-ami

**AWS: error while creating AMI from a Debian12 iso - ClientError: Unsupported kernel version 6.1.0**

What Linux Kernel Versions are Acceptable for AMI Import to AWS ?

We have a Debian11 (Bookworm) ISO and want to create an AMI using this iso.
We followed the steps from AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html) Importing a VM as an image using VM Import/Export but getting the below error.

`"ClientError: Unsupported kernel version 6.1.0-7-amd64"`

**Steps followed**

- Export image from VirtulBox
- Upload the image to S3
- Import the VM using the below command

`aws ec2 import-image --description "Debian 12 (Bookwarm) AMI" --disk-containers "file://containers.json"`

**containers.json**

```
[
    {
     "Description":"vm import",
     "Format":"ova",
     "UserBucket": {
        "S3Bucket": "debian12-iso",
        "S3Key": "Debian12_Bookwarm.ova"
}
}]
```

**Check upload status**

`aws ec2 describe-import-image-tasks --import-task-ids import-ami-074992884b301a9e7`

**Error Message:**

```
{
    "ImportImageTasks": [
        {
            "Description": "Debian 12 (Bookwarm) AMI",
            "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-074992884b301a9e7",
            "SnapshotDetails": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sde",
                    "DiskImageSize": 1346003968.0,
                    "Format": "VMDK",
                    "Status": "completed",
                    "UserBucket": {
                        "S3Bucket": "debian12-iso",
                        "S3Key": "Debian12_Bookwarm.ova"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Status": "deleted",
            "StatusMessage": "ClientError: Unsupported kernel version 6.1.0-7-amd64",
            "Tags": []
        }
    ]
}
```